# c# - How to count the number of occurences of a string in a ReadOnlyCollection field

Tags: c#, list, linq, count, readonly-collection

I have a ReadOnlyCollection of a Smartcard type from Microsoft.Clm.Shared.Smartcards namespace.

one of the fields/parameters of the smartcard object is AssingnedUserName.

**I need to be able to count how many times a smartcard with the same username exist in the list**,

something like:

```
[Pseudo Code]
int count = (smartcardCollection.AssignedUserName == my String).Count().
```

I tried to use the ReadOnlyCollection.Tolist() method, but I couldn't find the correct syntax to make it work.

I also found many examples but non for a ReadOnlyCollection object !

what is the best practice for achieving this ?

thanks

David.

Comment: [`Enumerable.Count` takes a predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb535181). See the examples.

Comment: David, can you please mention data type of smartcardCollection?

Comment: simple lambda sentence:

    `int Givaaty = smartcardCollection.Where(s => s.AssignedUserName == Rotem).Count();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use this

```
int count = smartcardCollection.Count(s=>s.AssignedUserName == my String);
```

LINQ [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb535181)  it takes a function to test each element for a condition

Comment: perfect, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the overload of `Count` or `Where` ... `Count`:

```
int count = smartcardCollection.Count(s => s.AssignedUserName == my String);
```

or

```
int count = smartcardCollection.Where(s => s.AssignedUserName == my String).Count();
```